# Brake slide pin keeps pushing itself out

Tags: honda, brakes, civic, disk-brakes

I drive a 1998 Honda Civic Ex. Lately I’ve been getting a pulsating noise from my passenger side tire during very slow speed braking (like approaching a stop sign)

I had only a couple months back serviced my brakes, cleaning pad ears/brackets, cleaning/greasing slide pins with a silicone grease.

While doing so, I noticed the top pins that had a rubber at the end would go in somewhat tight and when fully compressed would pull themselves out about an inch like a compressed spring being let go.

[image]

I tried cleaning the bracket hole of all grease, but same thing would happen. Tried burping any air by pulling on the dust boot while compressing the pin but nothing helps. It always springs back about an inch and does so slowly.

The bottom pins without the rubber at the end move smooth like they should with no springy action.

Couple questions:

- Can I simply just remove the rubber piece? What’s it for anyway and why doesn’t the bottom have it?
- Could I swap pins? (Top to bottom/bottom to top) I noticed in doing so the rubber ended one on the bottom doesn’t spring out, but my car’s service manual shows it goes on the top
- Why is the top slide pin constantly seizing up if it’s essentially always trying to spring back?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I suppose the rubber is to make the pin act like a spring/damper system. It's sealed so tight to keep air trapped like you describe, it at least has a spring/damping effect, wether it's intended or not. If intended, I think removing it may cause a little noise increase. If it's working improperly, it can also increase noise. Most odd constructions around brakes are to eliminate noise or NVH as we call it.

Comment: It seems to be seizing over time and creating a pulsating noise while braking. It’s the only one that seizes every time I check after a month or two of driving

Comment: Avoid swapping the guide pins around, if they're different lengths it can cause binding issues. The rubber bushing is for NVH you can remove it without any real drawback usually. Most likely the pin is pushing out because air is trapped under the pin. When you grease the pin only lightly coat it. Is the pin seizing because of rust or is it because the bushing is swollen? Have you tried replacing it?

Comment: @Ben What’s NVH? There’s no rust, I haven’t tried replacing the pin no but I do remember about two years ago the driver’s side top pin did not have the rubber. Someone had taken it off so I bought new ones for both sides. However the popping out was still occurring on the passenger side before I replaced the rubber

Comment: NVH = noise , vibration and harshness. How clean is the bore? If you remove the rubber does it slide easily?

Comment: @Ben I’ve tried cleaning the bore as much as I could with brake clean, q-tips, rag around a screwdriver but it still pops out. Without the rubber it does no push itself out

Comment: use a wire bore brush or similar tool to clean it out and try again. you could also use an appropriately sized drill bit or if you have access a media blasting cabinet.

Comment: @Ben Thanks I’ll try that. Do you know why this issue causes the top guide pins to seize over time and create a pulsating creaking noise at low braking speeds? Every time I check (when the noise eventually returns) the grease seems hardened but the bottom pins are always fine and move freely

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74596/discussion-between-ben-and-ohmmy).

Comment: @Ben I’m going to try cleaning the bore with a drill bit. Do you suggest using the bit by hand or with a drill? I’m not trying to expand the bore correct, just clean it?

Comment: @ohmmy yes just clean it out you can do it either way.

Comment: @Ben Still same issue so I removed them and went for a test drive. But unfortunately I could hear a “clunk” during braking. So I decided to cut about a 1/8th of an inch off so the rubber piece looked like a C. When installed it compressed together and was enough to keep it from springing out and no resistance now. Hopefully it continues working